# Skip iteration in For loop and repeat initialisation in Python

Tags: python, loops, iterator, skip

Let say I have `A=[2,4, 3 ,1]`, I want to compute the sum of element inside by skipping one element in each step.
What I try is:

```
s=[ ]
a=0
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A)):
        if i==j:
            continue
        else :
            a +=A[j]
    s.append(a)
```

When I print the result `s` I am getting

`print(s)`

```
s=[8, 14, 21, 30]
```

What I want to have is:

```
s=[ 8, 6, 7, 9]
```

Where

> 8=4+3+1  we skip `A[0]` 
> 6=2+3+1  we skip `A[1]` 
> 7=2+4+1  we skip `A[2]`  
> 9=2+4+3  we skip `A[3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement is already skipping an iteration, so all you need is to repeat the initialization. You can do this by re-initializing the sum variable (`a`) inside the outer loop instead of outside.

```
A = [2, 4, 3, 1]
s = []

for i in range(len(A)):
    a = 0
    for j in range(len(A)):
        if i == j:
            continue
        else:
            a += A[j]
    s.append(a)

print(s)
```

Output:

```
[8, 6, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 5):

How about computing the sum and then returning the sum minus each item, using list comprehension?

```py
sum_a = sum(A)
output = [sum_a - a for a in A]
print(output) # [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @j1-lee answer, but here's a nifty one-liner variation on that:

```py
output = [sum(A) - a for a in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a new list from slices, excluding the unwanted value, then sum

```
[sum(A[:i] + A[i+1:]) for i in range(len(A))]
```

Or, since `sum` results can themselves be added, use 2 slices

```
[sum(A[:i]) + sum(A[i+1:]) for i in range(len(A))]
```